# Unrecognized field "reconnectionTimeout" on Redisson 3.16.2

Tags: redisson

I'm trying to migrate my Redisson version to 3.16.2 and when I try to run the application I got this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "reconnectionTimeout" (class org.redisson.config.SingleServerConfig), not marked as ignorable (27 known properties: "subscriptionsPerConnection", "keepAlive", "sslKeystorePassword", "retryInterval", "retryAttempts", "pingConnectionInterval", "username", "connectTimeout", "password", "sslProvider", "timeout", "connectionMinimumIdleSize", "nameMapper", "idleConnectionTimeout", "sslTruststorePassword", "sslEnableEndpointIdentification", "address", "sslTruststore", "clientName", "subscriptionConnectionPoolSize", "connectionPoolSize", "subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize", "sslKeystore", "tcpNoDelay", "sslProtocols", "dnsMonitoringInterval", "database"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 8, column: 28] (through reference chain: org.redisson.config.Config["singleServerConfig"]->org.redisson.config.SingleServerConfig["reconnectionTimeout"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at org.redisson.config.ConfigSupport.fromYAML(ConfigSupport.java:175) ~[redisson-3.16.2.jar:3.16.2]
    at org.redisson.config.Config.fromYAML(Config.java:632) ~[redisson-3.16.2.jar:3.16.2]
```

My Redisson YAML like this, what should I change the keys with?

```
singleServerConfig:
  idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  pingConnectionInterval: 1000
  connectTimeout: 10000
  timeout: 3000
  retryAttempts: 3
  retryInterval: 1500
  reconnectionTimeout: 3000
  failedAttempts: 3
  password: null
  subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
  clientName: null
  address: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
  subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
  subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
  connectionMinimumIdleSize: 10
  connectionPoolSize: 64
  database: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It was replaced with `failedSlaveReconnectionInterval` parameter